# Only one media query working

Tags: css, media-queries

totally new to media queries and responsive design and I've fallen at the first hurdle.

I have the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #F00;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #224466;
    }           
}
```

And only the max-width: 500px works in that as I reduce the screen down it changes to the first colour, but as I reduce it further down to below 100px nothing else happens.

Where have I failed?

thanks

**SOLUTION:**

For anyone else with the same issue, here is the answer as provided by Sean Vieira.

The cascade still applies to active media queries so swapping them around resolves the issue) I also increased it from 100px as suggested by Roy Stanfield as the desktop browser might not go that small.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #224466;
    }     
    .entry-title {
        font-size: 2em; 
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #F00;
    }   
    .entry-title {
        font-size: 1em; 
    }
}
```

Comment: there is order in CSS for media queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cascade still applies to active media queries (if I understand it correctly).  If you look at what you wrote *without* the media queries, the problem becomes more evident:

```
#wrap {
        background: #F00;
}

#wrap {
        background: #224466;
}
```

Switching the order *should* fix the problem:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #224466;
    }           
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #F00;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @HedleyPhillips - I just created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GN7Q/1/) to test it out and it works for me (Chrome 20, Ubuntu 12) - where is it not working for you?

Comment: Hi. Let me strip everything back using a test page and test again.

Comment: Er. It works now. I created a new page with just a #wrap in it and added your css and it worked. Copied this over to the page I was having problems with and it also works. Gawd knows what I was doing last night. Maybe too much malt Whisky? Thanks for your help, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a normal desktop browser you may not be able to make it smaller than 100px. Try increasing your test widths to larger sizes like 500px and 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the ordering in the media queries in CSS.
Either change the order or 
Try to put `!important` over 
Use this one http://jsfiddle.net/fidrizers/8Pmuw/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `min-width` in one of your queries, so it becomes:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 100px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #F00;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 101px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrap {
            background: #224466;
    }           
}
```